# Showing a view from a UITabBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar, presentviewcontroller

I am trying to create a `picker` type thing when one `button` on a `UITabBar` is pressed. If you look at tumblrs iphone app, you will see what I mean. I assume they are presenting a `UIView` over whatever `viewcontroller` the user is currently on. How would I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question to me is more like a Custom Tab bar button question, i think what tumblr did is add a custom button in the middle of the tab bar, and present a modal view controller when click that button.

i did a very quick test on my test project, some number are hard coded for testing purpose, you may have to tweak that a little bit.

1. Add a custom button in the middle of your tab bar. (add following code to the `viewWillAppear` of the first view controller)

   ```
   - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
   {
       UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"classic-batman-logo.jpg"];
       UIImage *highlightImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"classic-batman-logo.jpg"];
       UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
       button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 60, 50);
       [button setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       [button setBackgroundImage:highlightImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

       button.center = CGPointMake(self.tabBarController.tabBar.center.x , 30);
       [button addTarget:self action:@selector(centerButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
       [self.tabBarController.tabBar addSubview:button];
   }
   ```
2. then simply present your target view controller in the centerButtonClicked function

   ```
   - (void)centerButtonClicked
   {
      UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
      vc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
      [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
   }
   ```

This is just a 10 minutes test i did, should look like this:

[image]

Maybe there are a couple of things you want to pay attention:

- change the hard coded center point when you implement your own code,
- and even better, you can create a custom tabBar with that center button, and set up a delegate method for that button click function. So every time when you click that button from different view controller, it will have different behavior.

Hope that gives you some rough idea about how to achieve this.

Comment: So the main problem is that I would like the background for the presented view controller to be blurred over the view controller, so there would be a blurred layer over the original view controller with the buttons on top. If you look at tumblr's the view controller you are pushing from is the background for the buttons

Comment: the way i did before is take a screen shot of your current view, blur it, pass to the 'going-to-be-presented' view controller as a background image. kill the present animation, so users won't realize that's a fake blur. and add some animation on the contents of 'going-to-be-presented' view controller.. but be honest, we kill the tab bar in the new version, tabbar seems to be a old fashion according to our designers...

Comment: Although a tab bar may be a little old fashioned now, I have never been a fan of the slide from the side controller like facebook used. I also think that a TabBar looks great with the ios 7 blur and complements a UINavigationBar nicely.

Comment: i agree, but sadly, i am not a designer. so i pretty much follow their guide lines.

Comment: @matthew maybe you can try this approach, let me know if you need some more helps. i can update my answer

Comment: Just trying it now, I had to go out to lunch before